# Parsing multiple xml files using xmldocument c#

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I am able to load multiple xml docs from my c drive but I need to find a way to put something into a loop so I can parse all of the xml's rather than just the first one.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{


    public static void Main()
    {

        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\r626890\Documents\BoxTesting\",      "*.xml");
        foreach (string files in filePaths)
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'",files);
        Console.WriteLine();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string file = filePaths[0].ToString();
        XmlNodeList xmlnode;
        doc.Load(file);

        XmlNodeList indexValue = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Index");

        for (int i = 0; i < indexValue.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Description: {0} ",             indexValue[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerXml);
            Console.WriteLine("Value:       {0} ", indexValue[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerXml);
        //  Console.WriteLine("{0}",i);
        }

        xmlnode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("FileName");
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("URI: {0} ", elemList[i].InnerXml.Split('_')[0]);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Type:        {0} ", xmlnode[i].InnerXml.Split('_')[1]);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("File Name:   {0} ", xmlnode[i].InnerXml);
                             Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("(Total # of files: {0})", ++i);
        }



        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forget the scope of :

```
foreach (string files in filePaths)
```

And you must load your document with :

```
doc.Load(files);
```

Instead of

```
doc.Load(file);
```

Because file is referenced to

```
string file = filePaths[0].ToString();
```

Therefore it's referenced to the first item of the collection filePaths (the first file)

I suggest you to rename "files" to "file" because it's not a collection, it's just one iterated items of your collection.

```
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\r626890\Documents\BoxTesting\",      "*.xml");
    foreach (string file in filePaths)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'",file);
        Console.WriteLine();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        //string file = filePaths[0].ToString();
        XmlNodeList xmlnode;
        doc.Load(file);

        XmlNodeList indexValue = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Index");

        for (int i = 0; i < indexValue.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Description: {0} ",             indexValue[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerXml);
            Console.WriteLine("Value:       {0} ", indexValue[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerXml);
        //  Console.WriteLine("{0}",i);
        }

        xmlnode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("FileName");
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("URI: {0} ", elemList[i].InnerXml.Split('_')[0]);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Type:        {0} ", xmlnode[i].InnerXml.Split('_')[1]);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("File Name:   {0} ", xmlnode[i].InnerXml);
                             Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("(Total # of files: {0})", ++i);
        }

    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: that has certainly solved it. It makes sense to put the entire thing in a foreach loop. Another question...how can I keep a count of each file displayed?

Comment: If you want to keep count, you must use : for (int i = 0; i < filesPaths.length; i++) instead of foreach and replace all the var "file" to filePaths[i], like you had made : string file = filePaths[0].ToString(); but replace "0" by "i" : string file = filePaths[i].ToString();, and keep the scope. Hope this help !

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate the help!!

Comment: Niels, I am now looking to write an XML based off these specific parsed elements (Doc type, description, value, file type, file name). What is the best approach for this? I m looking to create 1 big XML doc rather than creating 1 per each file.